# Fastest way to pack a flat c_long_Array of coordinates [x1,y1,z1, ...,] into a list of [(x1,y2,z3), ...] tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

I have a fixed length **[c_long_Array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_long)** (ctypes, basically an iterable) with coordanates stacked from left to right. The number of coordinates will not be known during runtime. As soon as an OUT_OF_RANGE element occurs there will be no more coordinates:

```
[x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, ..., OUT_OF_RANGE_INT, OUT_OF_RANGE_INT ,OUT_OF_RANGE_INT]
```

I want to convert this to a **list** on this format

```
[(x1, y1, z1), (x2, y2, z2), ..., (xn, yn, zn)]
```

My current code looks like this

```
OUT_OF_RANGE_INT = 2147483647

def parse_coordinates(raw_coordinates):
    packed_list = []
    i = 0
    while (x := raw_coordinates[i]) != OUT_OF_RANGE_INT:
        packed_list.append((x,
                            raw_coordinates[i + 1],  # y
                            raw_coordinates[i + 2])) # z
        i += 3
    return packed_list
```

This is a bottleneck in my application. How can I improve the speed of this function?

Answer (score 0):

Building such a large list will take time and a lot of memory. If you don't need to consume the whole list at once I would suggest to use `islice` and `takewhile` from the [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) to create a generator function:

```
>>> import array
>>> from itertools import islice, takewhile
>>> def test(c):
...     it = takewhile(lambda i: i < 30, c)
...     chunk = tuple(islice(it, 3))
...     while chunk:
...         yield chunk
...         chunk = tuple(islice(it, 3))
...
>>> for i in test(array.array('l', range(100))): print(i)
... 
(0, 1, 2)
(3, 4, 5)
(6, 7, 8)
(9, 10, 11)
(12, 13, 14)
(15, 16, 17)
(18, 19, 20)
(21, 22, 23)
(24, 25, 26)
(27, 28, 29)
```